# Does the ToS allow any third-party to run Turing-tests or otherwise unleash GAI-in-training onto our Stackexchange site?

Tags: discussion, policy, users, new-users

Let’s assume for a second Google, Facebook or an institution, agency or department under the Chinese Communist Party develops a big data language model and registers a user on a law.stackexchange; does the ToS allow them to wire the language model to autonomously and with or without supervision, ask questions on the site, comment, vote, make edits, etc.?

Does the ToS allow for a more generic use AI autonomously register the account and do the same?

This question comes from my suspicion of a user’s questions, answers and comments that I was vocal about, and am wondering how the site is regulated to allow or disallow something like the above examples.

Comment: [Autonomously, probably not](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/acceptable-use-policy): *"Accounts that are registered automatically or systematically will be removed and access will be permanently suspended."*

Comment: Why is this a meta-question - it seems like it belongs on the main site.

Comment: @DaleM I thought, since it does not relate to the law, but to the specific policies, rules, terms and conditions of the site: To me, it appears like a question, by definition, being _meta law stackexchange_ or... maybe meta.stackexchange?

Comment: @Nij Ok, we got #2 then.

Comment: @DaleM So, main meta site? I think law.stackexchange is probably better equipped to analyze the rules of the site then any other sites so even that could place it within jurisdiction.

Comment: Legal analysis of rules etc. are on topic for law SE (unless they are legal advice). What to do about someone breaking those rules is a mod/meta issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recently this was discussed on Meta SE: [Ban ChatGPT network-wide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384396/323179). So far, this has been treated as a policy issue and not a legal issue and the conclusion is that AI content is not allowed. Please flag any AI content that you see for moderator attention. Do not leave hostile comments for anyone, even if you suspect the content is AI generated.

Currently I have not seen any evidence that there are wholly autonomous systems that are operating on their own — it's humans who are copying and pasting. The ToS and the laws behind it were not written to govern AI, but I guess it wouldn't be old enough to use the site (13–16 years old).